# DIY ski machine

Tags: gym

Rather than pay $1000 plus for just a brand name, could one make a ski machine out of 2 simple cable, pulley and weights hung from a bar?

Or do you really need a flywheel as resistance?

Thanks

Comment: I asked the mods about migrating, but I'm not confident. It *might* fall under carpentry/woodworking, but the DIY site is more geared towards home improvement/building. I will update when I get an answer.

Comment: The flywheel resistance is really what makes the ski machine. It allows for the smaller bit of resistance at the bottom and the wind up before you pull again. Two cables on two pulleys would feel more like doing unilateral cable pulldowns.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about construction not use.

Comment: I talked to the moderators and they confirmed that the site is mostly for home construction/repair, and exercise equipment would only be on topic if it was about how to anchor it to the structure.

Comment: Have you checked youtube? https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=diy+ski+machine&page&utm_source=opensearch